# Why delete method of Eloquent (Laravel) fires a select?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have got this:

```
$obj = DeliveryNote::find($row->note_id);                                  
$obj->products()->delete();
$obj->delete();

$obj = Order::find($row->order_id);                                    
$obj->delete();
```

The log file of sql queries is this:

```
     - select * from `delivery_notes` where `delivery_notes`.`id` = ? limit 1
     - delete from `delivery_note_products` where `delivery_note_products`.`delivery_note_id` = ? and `delivery_note_products`.`delivery_note_id` is not null
     - delete from `delivery_notes` where `id` = ?

     - select * from `orders` where `orders`.`id` = ? limit 1
     - delete from `order_products` where `order_products`.`order_id` = ? and `order_products`.`order_id` is not null
     ¿¿?? ==>  select * from `delivery_notes` where `delivery_notes`.`id` = ? limit 1
```

I dont understand that, the Eloquent models havent got any strange.

```
class DeliveryNote extends Model
{
protected $table = 'delivery_notes';

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['...'];

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order');
}

...
```

I thought to comment "order()" method but it does nothing.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

You are using `find` which queries the database and returns an Eloquent model you then use `delete` on. If you use this way you can utilize [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events).

If you want to delete an entry in your database without getting an Eloquent response you need to skip `get` and `find` and just use `delete` instead.

```
Model::where('id', $id)->delete();
```